# Windows draggable under menu bar after second display

Tags: macos, display, menu-bar

Using OSX 10.8.5, I recently attached a second display to my 2013 Mac Air via the Thunderbolt port. Since removing this display I can now drag Finder and other windows under the menu bar. They pop back into viewable space on release, but this is visually annoying. How do I get the standard 'solid' menu bar behaviour back?

I have tried switching resolution but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible fix: edit the icon shortcuts in menu bar top right. For example `Sys Prefs > Date & Time > Show date in menu bar` (toggle it on/off). This seems to force the menu bar to refresh and fix the problem.